# Ansible | Add line & update /etc/hosts when outdated

Tags: ansible

I want to insert line or update my `/etc/hosts` if there is new data.
My following playbook is using `lineinfile`, however, I experienced issue that when one of my servers got new IP, the module would basically add new line containing the new IP, which is good, but the old one would still be present.

I'd like to do it as neat as possible, hopefully just use 1 module, not the combination of `lineinfile` & `replace`.

Example of existing playbook

```
- ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    line: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0 }} {{ hostvars[item].ansible_hostname }} {{ hostvars[item].ansible_hostname }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['web'] }}"
```

So... I basiaclly end up with:

*/etc/hosts*

```
192.168.1.1 web1.example.com web1
192.168.1.2 web2.example.com web2
192.168.1.3 web3.example.com web3
```

**Provisioned new web2:**

```
192.168.1.1 web1.example.com web1
192.168.1.2 web2.example.com web2
192.168.1.3 web3.example.com web3
192.168.1.4 web2.example.com web2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`regexp` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp) to tell `lineinfile` which lines to replace. That might look something like this:

```yaml
- hosts: web
  gather_facts: true

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: hosts
        line: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0 }} {{ hostvars[item].ansible_fqdn }} {{ hostvars[item].ansible_hostname }}"
        regexp: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_fqdn }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['web'] }}"
```

In my test environment, running it the first time produces:

```
172.17.0.4 web1.example.com web1
172.17.0.3 web2.example.com web2
172.17.0.2 web3.example.com web3
```

And if I update the ip address of `web2`, I get:

```
172.17.0.4 web1.example.com web1
172.17.0.5 web2.example.com web2
172.17.0.2 web3.example.com web3
```

Ansible has replaced the line for `web2.example.com`, rather than appending a new line.

Comment: Wow. Now I feel dumb.......... Thanks @larsks.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.11, you can use simpler [search_string](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-search_string) instead of *regexp*. For example, given the inventory for testing

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost ansible_connection=local

[web]
web1 ansible_host=10.1.0.61 ansible_fqdn=web1.example.com
web2 ansible_host=10.1.0.62 ansible_fqdn=web2.example.com
web3 ansible_host=10.1.0.63 ansible_fqdn=web3.example.com
```

The below play is idempotent

```yaml
- hosts: web

  tasks:

    - lineinfile:
        create: true
        path: /tmp/hosts
        search_string: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_fqdn }}"
        line: >-
          {{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }}
          {{ hostvars[item].ansible_fqdn }}
          {{ item }}
      loop: "{{ groups.web }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Creates the file */tmp/hosts* on the controller

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/hosts
10.1.0.61 web1.example.com web1
10.1.0.62 web2.example.com web2
10.1.0.63 web3.example.com web3
```